# Getting 'Attribute Error - Str has no attribute GET'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, get

Im trying to code this small program but for some reason, Im at a standstill at this part.
I want the code to print 'random answer' and 'another answer', but it ends up giving me an attribute error. Any help? Thanks..

Here's the code.

```
dictionary = {
'one':{'random':'random answer'},
'two':{'random':'another answer'}
}

for item in dictionary:
  print(item.get('random'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
dictionary = {
   'one':{'random':'random answer'},
   'two':{'random':'another answer'}
}

for key, item in dictionary.items():
   print(item.get('random'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over dictionary, you can use `dictionary.items()` which gives you a tuple of key value pair. You can take them in `item, value`. Then, you can use `value.get(another_key)`

```
dictionary = {
    'one': {'random': 'random answer'},
    'two': {'random': 'another answer'}
}

# item -> 'one' and value -> '{'random': 'random answer'}'
# value will be the dictionary on which you can call get function
for item, value in dictionary.items():
    print(value.get('random'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you iterate over a dict in Python, you actually iterate over the keys of the dictionary, not over the key-value pairs. So in your code item is the key and thus the `get('random')` fails.

To iterate over key-value pairs you can use the `.items()` method. This way you will loop over tuples of key-value pairs:

```py
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    print(value.get('random'))
```